# React setState doesnt actually change the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following onClick event:

```
const handleClickOpen = (id) => {
        const newPieChartData=pieChartData.map((item)=>{
            if (item.id===id){
                const newItem={
                    ...item , open:true
                }
                console.log(newItem)
                return newItem
            } return item
        })
        
        setPieChartData(newPieChartData)
        console.log(pieChartData)
        addPieChartGroup(id)
    };
```

And this is how I declare the onClick event in a child component:

```
onClick={()=>handleClickOpen(id)}
```

Yet the state

```
[
        {
            id:uuidv4(),
            data:[],
            open:false,
        }
    ]
```

doesnt change at all , which is reflected in the console.log
(This is logged for newItem `{id: "4d95df0a-d463-4981-91ec-20ea323414e0", data: Array(0), open: true}` and this is logged for the pieChartData:{id: "4d95df0a-d463-4981-91ec-20ea323414e0", data: Array(0), open: false}) . Why is that ? Thank you very much !

Comment: Setting state is asynchronous, so your console.log will show the old value.

Comment: As @ChrisG already told that setState is working asynchronously. What you can do is console log outside handleClickOpen function and then verify you state after click

Comment: @ChrisG I have also logged it outside the handler and I get the same result. Furthermore, I know that it didnt make any change because if open was being set to true , it would trigger the rendering of an additional component, which is not... So I guess there may be something else?

Comment: @MuhammadBilalBangash Yep have done that, same result

Comment: You need to post a [mre] so we can debug it then.

Comment: yes please share your code anywhere codesandbox etc

Comment: i think return is incorrect` if (item.id===id){
                const newItem={
                    ...item , open:true
                }
                console.log(newItem)
                return newItem
            }  else return item`

Comment: @zahrazamani I don't think so , because if the, `if` branch was entered the second return, would turn obsolete